Why is it that I cannot tree shake icon fonts?
I am able to run the app on my computer. But when I create a pull request on Github and push the code, it is showing an error while checking:
"This application cannot tree shake icons fonts. It has non-constant instances of IconData at the following locations: Product_Model"
The code snippet as follows:
class ProductModel extends Equatable {
  final DocumentReference selfRef;
  final String productName;
  final String description;
  final DocumentReference defaultPlan;
  final IconData icon;
  const ProductModel(
      {required this.selfRef,
      required this.productName,
      required this.defaultPlan,
      required this.icon,
      required this.description});
  factory ProductModel.fromSnapshot(
      DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) {
    final data = snapshot.data()!;

    return ProductModel(
        selfRef: snapshot.reference,
        productName: data['name'] as String,
        defaultPlan: data['defaultPlan'],
        icon: IconData(data['iconId'] as int, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
        description: data['description'] as String);
  }

 @override
  List<Object> get props => [selfRef, productName, defaultPlan, icon];
}

Why is this running on my computer but not Github? What is the fix for this?

The Tree shaking process in flutter is for removing any unused code and resources, including unused IconData instances from the final build to reduce the size of the app. And now that you pull the code from GitHub it complain about this part of the code
icon: IconData(data['iconId'] as int, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
it is because IconData is being instantiated from data retrieved.
you should avoid dynamically instantiating IconData instances based on runtime data, because it prevents Tree shaking icons fonts.
to solve this issue you can try to move the IconData instantiation outside of the class definition; This way, IconData becomes a constant value, allowing Flutter to tree shake it properly.
Try this:
class ProductModel extends Equatable {
  final DocumentReference selfRef;
  final String productName;
  final String description;
  final DocumentReference defaultPlan;
  final IconData icon;

  const ProductModel({
    required this.selfRef,
    required this.productName,
    required this.defaultPlan,
    required this.icon,
    required this.description,
  });

  factory ProductModel.fromSnapshot(
    DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot,
  ) {
    final data = snapshot.data()!;

    return ProductModel(
      selfRef: snapshot.reference,
      productName: data['name'] as String,
      defaultPlan: data['defaultPlan'],
      icon: productIcon(data['iconId'] as int),
      description: data['description'] as String,
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [selfRef, productName, defaultPlan, icon];
}

// Function to get IconData based on iconId
IconData productIcon(int iconId) {
  switch (iconId) {
    case 1:
      return Icons.abc;
    case 2:
      return Icons.ac_unit_sharp;
    // Add more cases as needed
    default:
      // Return a default icon or handle invalid iconIds
      return Icons.error;
  }
}

here you fetch 'iconId' and pass it to productIcon function in-order to return The icon with the same 'iconId'.
